# django markup processor that handles latex code

Tags: django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Django has a built in template filter than can process restructured text. Is it possible to process latex code with this in the same way as sphinx (documentation generator) handles latex code, using e.g.

```
.. math::

   (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2

   (a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2
```

which gets converted to png images?

I know I could write my own rst processor to handle latex code for use in my django, I just wondered if this has already been done already.

thanks for any suggestions or advice
-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I am looking into this myself.  emesik's solution [on github](https://github.com/emesik/django_mathlatex) appears to do exactly what you want.

This is straight out of his documentation:

```
Render PNG images of math formulas written in LaTeX notation. It's simple as hell:

    {% load mathlatex %}
    {% math %}
        E = mc^2
    {% endmath %}
```

---

Though, you may be more interested in something like [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which lets you convert between various different formats such as html, markdown, reStructuredText, latex, etc. Also, you can [try an online demo.](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try).